# Getting error while iterating through list of participants in selenium with wait method

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

When I debug the program all the 3 participants are selected but when I run it gives error for second participant that

java.lang.IllegalStateException: The Network Member can not be found

Input list has following values

1. Group Member
2. Network Member
3. LD Admin

[image: This is the selector]
[image: Xpath for dropdown]

```
  public MessagesPage findRecipient(List userRecipient) throws InterruptedException {


    int userCount = userRecipient.size();
    int index=0;
    for( Object tempUser : userRecipient){
        WebElement rightUser = null;
        SeleniumUtils.waitElementVisible(driver, searchUser);
        searchUser.sendKeys(tempUser.toString());

        //output element of drop down search user name
        By byUserSearchResult = By.xpath("//tbody[@class='js-pages']/tr/td");

        //Wait till the user list is available.
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(byUserSearchResult));
        List<WebElement> resultTable = driver.findElements(byUserSearchResult);

        //The code is failing here for 3rd element in the list
        for (WebElement user : resultTable) {
            String check = user.getText();
            if (check.contentEquals(tempUser.toString())) rightUser = user;
        }

        if (rightUser == null)
            throw new IllegalStateException("The " + tempUser.toString() + " can not be found");

        rightUser.click();

    }
```

Comment: Update the question with text based relevant HTML

Comment: when you get the resultTable list use: List<WebElement> resultTable = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(byUserSearchResult));   Remember that this only waits until the first item is available... so you need to loop and try/catch the .getText() calls to check for staleElement exceptions.  If that exception is caught you need to find that list again...(not done populating...)

Answer (score 0):

You need to induce WebDriverWait (*elementToBeClickable*) for each item.

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(rightUser));
rightUser.click();
```